# NSViewController not dealloc'd when outlets are bound

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, iboutlet, nsviewcontroller, nsstoryboard

I have the following files:

**Main.storyboard**

This is the same as the default storyboard created when creating a new project with a few additions: There is a button in the view which is connected to the `button` outlet of the view controller (instance of `ViewController`) and the `doTheThing:` action on the view controller.

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *button;
@property (weak) NSViewController *controller;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)doTheThing:(id)sender {
    if (self.controller) {
        NSLog(@"Removing %@", self.controller);
        [self.controller.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.controller removeFromParentViewController];
    } else {
        self.controller = [[NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Another" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialController];
        [self addChildViewController:self.controller];
        [self.view addSubview:self.controller.view];
        NSLog(@"Adding %@", self.controller);
    }
}

@end
```

**Another.storyboard**

A simple storyboard containing a single scene (view controller + view) that is set to the initial controller and is an instance of `AnotherViewController`. There is a label in the view **that is not connected to any outlet**.

**AnotherViewController.m**

```
#import "AnotherViewController.h"

@interface AnotherViewController ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *label;
@end

@implementation AnotherViewController

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Deallocing AnotherViewController %@", self);
}

@end
```

When I run the app and click the button, it adds the view controller and view from `Another.storyboard`, and when I click the button again they are removed and the instance of `AnotherViewController` is deallocated.

However, if I connect the label in `Another.storyboard` to the `label` outlet on the `AnotherViewController`, the deallocation never occurs. Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

**Edit:** I do have a few workarounds, but they aren't very desirable and I would prefer to understand why the recommended way (storyboards and outlets) isn't working properly.

Undesirable workaround 1: Do the same thing but load the view controller and view from a XIB file. This works as expected, but ideally I would be able to do the same thing using storyboards.

Undesirable workaround 2: Bind all my outlets manually in code in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method. This is just tedious and ugly as it requires iterating through all the view's subviews and comparing identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple have confirmed (via bug report) that this is a known issue and will be fixed in OS X 10.10.3.